# Why we cannot use P=I2R to determine the current through the cable?

Tags: power, current, resistance

Why we cannot use P=I2R to determine the current through the cable? The current flow through the cable is affected by the resistance of cable right? But when I use P = IV and P=I<sup>2</sup>R, I got different value of I.

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework questions with no attempt at a solution are off-topic. Hint: how much power is the cable dissipating?

Comment: If I am delivering a pizza, is it consumed at the destination or on the road as I drive?

Comment: You can. If you have the correct P.

Comment: @DKNguyen - don't give it to me to deliver then!

Comment: @Andyaka The only perfect pizza deliverymen are super-delivering pizza deliverymen. For all others, some pizza must be expected to be consumed along the way but if they are properly designed, this should be a small fraction compared to the amount of pizza that ends up getting delivered.

Comment: @L'Ben, I put the image back in your question as it makes no sense without it. Since this is homework you need to show the calculations that you say you have done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use \$P = I^2R\$ to find the power consumed by a resistive element (such as a cable with dc current) but you must be careful about the quantities in the equation.

\$P\$ is the power consumed **by the cable itself**.

\$I\$ is the current **through the cable**.

\$R\$ is the resistance **of the cable itself**.

Think carefully about the quantities you are given.

Comment: That is to say, there are two different amounts of power hidden in the question.

Comment: @DKNguyen, is that in question 'b' or in question 'b'?

Comment: @Transistor In question b, of course.